# Shared memory Master/Slave process to access single serial port

Tags: shared-memory

I am creating a Daemon in Unix that will have exclusive access to a serial port "/dev/tty01". I am planning to create a Master - Slave process paradigm where there is one master (the daemon) and multiple slaves.
I was thinking of having a structure in "Shared memory" where the slaves can access, and there is only one writer to the memory so I most likely wont need a semaphore. The data will be updated fairly slowly, once every minute for example.
I was looking into what would be the best possible way to do this, also if I have a structure in shared memory, how can I guarantee that the structure will be contiguous in memory? It is a requirement I must have.

The master program will have its own internal data structure that is being updated from the serial port, and then it will modify the data and send it out to a global structure that is in shared memory for the clients to use.

I dont have much experience in Unix IPC, but what would be the easiest way to do this? By the way the clients will all be different processes ran by other users locally on the system

It must used shared memory it is a requirement of the project. Also, is it possible to copy one structure into another if the second structure has different data types?

Answer (score 0):

1. A shared memory segment is a contiguous piece of memory from your process' view.
2. The calls to create and handle shared memory are rather simple (shmctl/shmat/shmdt)
3. The layout of the structures in the memory is up to you. Best is a fixed header like a type field and the rest as an union.
4. For your client processes you could provide a little lib (static or shared) with a set of functions to retrieve data, thereby hiding the shared memory and the structures.